# Algorithm for positioning ships in Battleship game

Tags: algorithm, position

I have to implement [Battleship game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_%28game%29) in C++. It would be *Human* vs *Computer* game.

Everything is quite straight forward except positioning computer's ships on start of the game. Computer's ships' positions should be random. But how should I (optimally) choose cells of the array for ships?

Writing code which would set random position for a ship and then check if cells in the neighborhood are empty could be very time consuming.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should edit your question to state the rules you said you didn't mention.

Answer (score 2):

The space is so large that there are always free cells to use, so repeatedly attempting to place the ship, then failing, is perfectly fine.

You can achieve sufficiently close-to-optimal positioning by making sure your ships don't touch (since that might give the opponent free information if they are destroying a ship), and also by placing shorter ships with ever-so-slightly more probability near the edges (to offset the fact that larger ships are more likely to be found near the center).

Comment: But array size doesn't have to be 10x10. I'll make it more flexible. Repeating random attempts is not solution here. I want to do it OPTIMALLY. Random attempts are very time consuming.
I haven't written it above but ships can't 'touch' in this game (because game rules told so; it's a must).

Comment: @patryk.beza: 1) I'm aware the size can be anything. I still stand by my assertion, because a game of dense battleship is not interesting. 2) Then you should edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use a linked list, where each node is a link to a square on the board.  You can then a) generate a random node and b) as you place ships remove nodes from the list.  You can remove extra nodes from around the placed ship to make give that ship some room (don't want your ships to touch ;)

Comment: Possibly not the best choice of data structures, given the board is a 2D grid; cells have multiple adjacent cells, so you'll end up needing more code to determine the neighbours, than if you used a jagged/multi-dimension array.

Comment: Each node is a link to a square on a board. Implement that however you want - you could use a struct/class "Square" with properties X and Y and you can then determine neighbors the exact same way you would have done it with your jagged array.

Answer (score 0):

If it's computer vs. computers, you just have to make sure you place the ships randomly across the board such that none of the ships are adjacent to each other.

However, since you're playing a human you can get a little more creative. It's like the game rock-paper-scissors where you can gain an edge by exploiting human tendencies.

Comment: And that was the question: How to optimally place the ships randomly across the board such that none of the ships are adjacent to each other?